# How to capture packets and forward http request to a given http proxy

Tags: android, packet-capture, http-proxy

I've searched here and get a clue that I may use VpnService, but there're few samples in using VpnService. Could someone please tell me how to program with vpnservice?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this within Android itself. I know this can be done by using Burpsuite monitoring your Android packets and then forwarding the http request to any http you provide in the Burpsuite. However, this is done through a PC.

so what you have is:

Android App ---> Making Http request or what not --->Burpsuite on PC interfering these requests and modyfing them if needed and then forwarding/dropping the request ---> To the site/proxy.

Note: The Android and PC has to be using the same network.

I might have understood this wrong. Do let me know :)

Comment: I really want to do this within Android itself. And the phone is not supposed to be rooted.